# Xcode 13.1 show source code framework from app

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, frameworks, xcode13

I want to hide my framework's source code so that it cannot be accessed from App with "Cmd + click + Jump to definition".

Any flags to do this from the build settings?

I tried this with Xcode 11.3.1 works fine. it doesn't show the source code, it just shows public methods, but Xcode 13 shows implementation.

Sample in Xcode 11.3.1

```
public class Operation {
    public static func plus(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int
}
```

Sample in Xcode 13.1

```
public class Operation {
   public static func plus(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
       return a + b
   }
}
```

Comment: If you distribute your's framework with open source code, why it's an issue?

Comment: I want distribute this framework to client like XCode 11.3, it only show prototipes, it doesn't show implementation.

Comment: Any way in XCode 11.3 your's frameworks was distributed with code. If sources wasn't opened by cmd+jump to definition it doesn't mean that there is no other way to open yours sources. For example it is possible to step in in debug

Comment: Anyway, can I hide source code in Xcode 13 using the built settings options?

Comment: The only option to hide source code is to distribute framework with binary

Answer (score 1):

Watch the location of shown source code. For example, if you add your .framework file to your app, when you right-click "jump to definition", it's showing code from the working copy of a framework (different location). So when I zipped the folder with working copy of framework, then source code didn't show up, only public things.